# Does corrwith() work with time series data?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I am comparing two dataframes of time series data. I am grouping them by either count of month/week etc and want to know if corrwith is suitable to calculate correlation.

for example two data frames split by week that look like:

df1

|  | date | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2019-04-14 | 1 |
| 1 | 2019-04-21 | 11 |
| 2 | 2019-04-28 | 12 |
| 3 | 2019-05-05 | 24 |
| 4 | 2019-05-12 | 24 |

df2

|  | date | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2019-04-14 | 10 |
| 1 | 2019-04-21 | 15 |
| 2 | 2019-04-28 | 16 |
| 3 | 2019-05-05 | 23 |
| 4 | 2019-05-12 | 24 |

So would the following code work to show potential between the two time series?

```
df1.corrwith(df2.count)
```

Answer (score 0):

The expected output is unclear, but you might want:

```
df1.set_index('date').corrwith(df2.set_index('date')['count'])

# or, for all matching columns
df1.set_index('date').corrwith(df2.set_index('date'))
```

This will set the date as index to perform the correct alignment used in [`corrwith`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corrwith.html).

Output:

```
count    0.996094
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Apologies i did this above. Thanks

Comment: @teebee99, so does my answer fulfill your needs?

Comment: It wasn't so much code i wanted help with, it was more if corrwith was a good function to compare time series data correlations. Thanks

Comment: I see, well then I would say that the fact that it is a time series is not really relevant here. You just want to form pairs of values for the correlation. You might also be interested in regression fit

Answer (score 0):

With `Series` you must use `corr` function :

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2019-04-14', '2019-04-21', '2019-04-28', '2019-05-05', '2019-05-12'],
           'count': [1, 11, 12, 24, 24],
           })

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2019-04-14', '2019-04-21', '2019-04-28', '2019-05-05', '2019-05-12'],
           'count': [10, 15, 16, 23, 24],
           })

r = df['count'].corr(df2['count'])

print(r)
```

```
0.9960937567717464
```

Comment: so you need to change the dataframe to a series to check correlation on time series?

Comment: ```corwith``` is only for dataframe and ```corr``` is for both. ```corwith``` is used for correlation between two dataframes. ```corr``` is used in a dataframe for correlation between its own columns and is used in Series for correlation between two series.